# Read specific DICOM tags from multiple files and write into csv

Tags: python, csv, pydicom

I have several DICOM files in one folder, and I would like to extract 1 specific tag (e.g. CTDIvol) from every DICOM file, and write it into a csv. How can I do that using Python?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The reading of one file is working with pydicom. However, I have a few thousand DICOM files, and and I would like to extract from them the PatientName, CTDIvol and ScanLength info and write them into one csv file. The problem for me is more complicated, as the CTDIvol is in a Sequence.